# How do I add roles in discord.py in latest version?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, roles

This is the code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    moji = await bot.get_channel(775355712271941647).send("react to get banana")
    await moji.add_reaction(emoji='')


@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):

    if reaction.emoji == "":
        role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="banana")
        await user.add_role(role)
```

This is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'add_role'
```

I searched this everywhere, but every answer told me to do the `user.add_role`. I also checked the documentation, I can't find it. Please help. Oh, also, the `client.add_role(user, name)` doesn't work either

Comment: await user.add_role(role) > Change it to await user.add_roles(role)

Comment: @Sofia thanks, it solved my problem lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) object contains an attribute for [`add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles).

Changing `add_role` to `add_roles` should fix the issue:

```
await user.add_roles(role)
```